# ViewBinder cast error with android 4.0

Tags: android, casting, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I get following error(line 19 is //XXX in the code):

> 04-10 10:35:08.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.**TextView cannot be cast
>   to android.widget.CheckBox** 04-10 10:35:08.301:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12417):  at
>   ms.jung.andorid.caldavtodo.CalDavToDoViewBinder.setViewValue(CalDavToDoViewBinder.java:19)

My code:

```
class CalDavToDoViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();

        if(viewId == R.id.checkBox) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view; //XXX

                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalDavToDoProvider.STATE)) == 1)
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                }
                return true;

        }
        else if(viewId == R.id.colorBar)
        {

                int color = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalDavToDoProvider.COLOR));

                TextView colorBar = (TextView)view;
                colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color);

                return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I am very confused, because `R.id.checkBox` is definitely a `CheckBox`.

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colorBar"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:text="@string/colorBarDefault" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:text="@string/checkBoxDefault" >
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sqlID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sqlIDDefault"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLUTION :**

**EDIT : CLEANING THE PROJECT HELPED!**

Answer (score 1):

use `view.setTag(objTextview);`

```
TextView colorBar = (TextView)view.getTag();
```

Comment: Object of (?)kind, ie. Textview, Button, any control or string, int, array etc...

Comment: where should i put "use view.setTag(objTextview);" exactly in my code?

Comment: R.id.colorBar is a TextView, but the problem is at the checkBox: R.id.checkBox

Comment: Are you sure R.id.checkBox is Checkbox may be you assigned to textview, just clean your project run it

Comment: okay cleaning the project did the job ... thanks for your help!